# What is the bottleneck in this primes related predicate?

Tags: performance, prolog, primes

So here it is : I'm trying to calculate the sum of all primes below two millions  (for [this problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=10)), but my program is very slow. I do know that the algorithm in itself is terribly bad and a brute force one, but it seems way slower than it should to me.
Here I limit the search to 20,000 so that the result isn't waited too long.
I don't think that this predicate is difficult to understand but I'll explain it anyway : I calculate the list of all the primes below 20,000 and then sum them. The sum part is fine, the primes part is really slow.

```
problem_010(R) :-
    p010(3, [], Primes),
    sumlist([2|Primes], R).
p010(20001, Primes, Primes) :- !.
p010(Current, Primes, Result) :-
    (
        prime(Current, Primes)
    ->  append([Primes, [Current]], NewPrimes)
    ;   NewPrimes = Primes
    ),
    NewCurrent is Current + 2,
    p010(NewCurrent, NewPrimes, Result).
prime(_, []) :- !.
prime(N, [Prime|_Primes]) :- 0 is N mod Prime, !, fail.
prime(ToTest, [_|Primes]) :- prime(ToTest, Primes).
```

I'd like some insight about why it is so slow. Is it a good implementation of the stupid brute force algorithm, or is there some reason that makes Prolog fall?

EDIT : I already found something, by appending new primes instead of letting them in the head of the list, I have primes that occur more often at start so it's ~3 times faster. Still need some insight though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, before the edit the problem was just the algorithm (imho).
As you noticed, it's more efficient to check if the number is divided by the smaller primes first; in a finite set, there are more numbers divisible by 3 than by 32147.

Another algorithm improvement is to stop checking when the primes are greater than the square root of the number.

Now, after your change there are indeed some prolog issues:
you use append/3. append/3 is quite slow since you have to traverse the whole list to place the element at the end.
Instead, you should use difference lists, which makes placing the element at the tail really fast.

Now, what is a difference list? Instead of creating a normal list [1,2,3] you create this one [1,2,3|T]. Notice that we leave the tail uninstantiated. Then, if we want to add one element (or more) at the end of the list we can simply say T=[4|NT]. awesome?

The following solution (accumulate primes in reverse order, stop  when prime>sqrt(N), difference lists to append) takes 0.063 for 20k primes and 17sec for 2m primes while your original code took 3.7sec for 20k and the append/3 version 1.3sec.

```
problem_010(R) :-
    p010(3, Primes, Primes),
    sumlist([2|Primes], R).
p010(2000001, _Primes,[]) :- !.                                %checking for primes till 2mil
p010(Current, Primes,PrimesTail) :-
    R is sqrt(Current),
    (
        prime(R,Current, Primes)
    ->  PrimesTail = [Current|NewPrimesTail]
    ;   NewPrimesTail = PrimesTail
    ),
    NewCurrent is Current + 2,
    p010(NewCurrent, Primes,NewPrimesTail).
prime(_,_, Tail) :- var(Tail),!.
prime(R,_N, [Prime|_Primes]):-
    Prime>R.
prime(_R,N, [Prime|_Primes]) :-0 is N mod Prime, !, fail.
prime(R,ToTest, [_|Primes]) :- prime(R,ToTest, Primes).
```

also, considering adding the numbers while you generate them to avoid the extra o(n) because of sumlist/2
in the end, you can always implement the AKS algorithm that runs in polynomial time (XD)

Comment: @false that's...interesting. indeed, it returns 142913828922 although I would swear that it returned 21171191 the first time :s checking it atm

Comment: Sorry, I retracted my comment: You are using  a bigger numer! Not 20001 but 2000001

Comment: @false yeah, I just realized it tooXD np!

Comment: I knew about difference lists but never really came to use them before, thanks for this and the other good advice !

Comment: I don't want to spoil this again, but that kind of difference list leads often to very hard to maintain programs that are worse than any imperative program you can imagine. It seems much cleaner to compute the sum on the fly and use the list only to accumulate primes below sqrt(2000001). Anyway, a better stepper than +2 will be the most interesting improvement.

Answer (score 4):

First, Prolog does not fail here.

There are very smart ways how to generate prime numbers. But as a cheap start simply accumulate the primes in reversed order! (7.9s -> 2.6s) In this manner the smaller ones are tested sooner. Then, consider to test only against primes up to 141. Larger primes cannot be a factor.

Then, instead of stepping only through numbers not divisible by 2, you might add 3, 5, 7.

There are people writing papers on this "problem". See, for example [this paper](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3127), although it's a bit of a sophistic discussion what the "genuine" algorithm actually was, 22 centuries ago when the latest release of the abacus was celebrated as [Salamis tablets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salamis_Tablet).

Comment: Yup so this is more of an algorithm problem, that is precisely what I wanted to know ! Thanks. I'll take a look at this paper.

Comment: what's a "Salaminic tables"? Googling didn't help. :) (for 2,000,000 the limit is 1414 btw).

Comment: @Will Ness: Sorry, did not know that this adjective does not exist in English, I corrected it (including a link).

Comment: thanks! as for the "genuineness" of [the sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) it depends upon whether the Greeks had [algorisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorism) or not, to find the next multiple of a prime directly by addition - *jumping* there, as the modern CPUs do, instead of *crawling* along the table counting "each 3rd", or "each 13th" number etc. Which if they did so, would make the today's sieve of Eratosthenes definitely *not* a genuine one.

Comment: @Will Ness: The Salamis tablets might be a witness to a better number representation. But "jumping" does have some nonconstant access (in the general case...). But the major point was that the original sieve requires to lay down the entries 1..n first. Turner's pure functional version however (which actually is rather some form of trial division) does not need to know the n to start!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, appending at the end of a list using `append/3` is quite slow. If you must, then use difference lists instead. (Personally, I try to avoid `append/3` as much as possible)

Secondly, your `prime/2` always iterates over the whole list when checking a prime. This is unnecessarily slow. You can instead just check id you can find an integral factor up to the square root of the number you want to check.

```
problem_010(R) :-
    p010(3, 2, R).
p010(2000001, Primes, Primes) :- !.
p010(Current, In, Result) :-
    ( prime(Current) -> Out is In+Current ; Out=In ),
    NewCurrent is Current + 2,
    p010(NewCurrent, Out, Result).

prime(2).
prime(3).
prime(X) :-
    integer(X),
    X > 3,
    X mod 2 =\= 0,
    \+is_composite(X, 3).   % was: has_factor(X, 3)

is_composite(X, F) :-       % was: has_factor(X, F) 
    X mod F =:= 0, !.
is_composite(X, F) :- 
    F * F < X,
    F2 is F + 2,
    is_composite(X, F2).
```

Disclaimer: I found this implementation of `prime/1` and `has_factor/2` by googling.

This code gives:

```
?- problem_010(R).
R = 142913828922
Yes (12.87s cpu)
```

Here is even faster code:

```
problem_010(R) :-
    Max = 2000001,
    functor(Bools, [], Max),
    Sqrt is integer(floor(sqrt(Max))),
    remove_multiples(2, Sqrt, Max, Bools),
    compute_sum(2, Max, 0, R, Bools).

% up to square root of Max, remove multiples by setting bool to 0
remove_multiples(I, Sqrt, _, _) :- I > Sqrt, !.
remove_multiples(I, Sqrt, Max, Bools) :-
    arg(I, Bools, B),
    (
        B == 0
    ->
        true % already removed: do nothing
    ;
        J is 2*I, % start at next multiple of I
        remove(J, I, Max, Bools)
    ),
    I1 is I+1,
    remove_multiples(I1, Sqrt, Max, Bools).

remove(I, _, Max, _) :- I > Max, !.
remove(I, Add, Max, Bools) :-
     arg(I, Bools, 0), % remove multiple by setting bool to 0
     J is I+Add,
     remove(J, Add, Max, Bools).

% sum up places that are not zero
compute_sum(Max, Max, R, R, _) :- !.
compute_sum(I, Max, RI, R, Bools) :-
    arg(I, Bools, B),
    (B == 0 -> RO = RI ;  RO is RI + I ),
    I1 is I+1,
    compute_sum(I1, Max, RO, R, Bools).
```

This runs an order of magnitude faster than the code I gave above:

```
?- problem_010(R).
R = 142913828922
Yes (0.82s cpu)
```

Comment: really nice **prime/1** and **has_factor/2** predicates ! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, they are not mine. I found them through Google by looking for sieve of erastothenes. However, I have added another version to my answer that does not use these predicates and is much faster by avoding lists.

Comment: The main idea for the second version was using a term instead of a list, so that I can delete the multiples much faster by using `arg/3` instead of iterating over a list to find them.

Comment: Your examples are very interesting. Thanks for posting them. (I let the answer to thanosQR because it's more on topic but I really appreciate that :)) I'd +2 if I could !

Comment: fixed an error for you. :) you can start removal from `I*I` instead of just `2*I`, it'll give you another speedup.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using for example a sieve method ("Sieve of Eratosthenes"): First create a list [2,3,4,5,6,....N], using for example numlist/3. The first number in the list is a prime, keep it. Eliminate its multiples from the rest of the list. The next number in the remaining list is again a prime. Again eliminate its multiples. And so on. The list will shrink quite rapidly, and you end up with only primes remaining.

Comment: I'll implement it when I'll be done with this brute force thing to see how it goes :) thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: you should only ***mark*** numbers as composite, ***not remove*** them, or you won't be able to count properly and will be forced to test divide each in isolation, or to compare them with generated multiples - still worse than just marking a number at a given offset. Of course using compound term as an array substitute is a tremendous performance booster, here.