# ERROR: Undefined procedure: (+)/2

Tags: prolog, primes

I'm new in SWI-Prolog and I want to check prime function in Prolog.

```
prime(N) :-
    N > 1,
    M is N - 1,
    check(N, M).

check(_, 1).
check(N, M) :-
    M > 1,
    R is N - M * N / M,
    R > 0,
    P is M - 1,
    check(N, P).
```

but when I ask `2 + 2` or another operator like `(*)/2`, `(/)/2`,... in Prolog it says: `undefined procedure: (+)/2`.
I think it is for `see` or `tell`. I reassign `see(user)` and `tell(user)` but this error occurs again.
why?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on SWI-Prolog 5.10.1. Did you try running this in a fresh, clean Prolog environment?

Comment: The error can't arise from the code you show, that seems syntactically correct. On the 'command line' (it's called REPL), maybe you should enter something like `?- X is 2+2.`

Answer (score 6):

In SWI prolog 6.0.2 division as you used it returns floating point number. So `prime(13)` for example will fail, as remainder is 0. Integer division uses operator `//`. But check prolog SWI functions `rem` and `mod`.

Also you would like to have a cut after first definition of `check`, otherwise prolog will explore the second definition, which will return false. Cut ensures that after it checked all natural numbers smaller than N, it stops with success.

Here is the corrected code which behaves as desired in SWI Prolog 6.0.2.

```
prime(N) :-
    N > 1,
    M is N - 1,
    check(N, M).

check(_, 1) :- !.
check(N, M) :-
    M > 1,
    R is N mod M,
    R > 0,
    P is M - 1,
    check(N, P).
```

Answer (score 4):

About your error, check this out:

```
?- 2+2.
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (+)/2

?- X is 2+2.    
X = 4
```

You're supposed to use `is` in Prolog to force the evaluation of arithmetic expressions. Try typing "`help(is).`" at SWI-Prolog's prompt.

But your algorithm is massively inefficient, on two accounts. First, you check the candidate number for divisibility by all its preceding numbers, while only those not greater than its square root are enough (if `a*b=n` and `a >= sqrt(n)` then `b =< sqrt(n)`).

Then, you test in reversed order. Multiples of smaller factors are much more frequent than of larger ones, so the testing will get cut off much much earlier when done in ascending order, making the overall program run much *much* faster. Lastly, no need to test by any even number except 2:

```
prime(2).
prime(N) :- N > 1,
    N mod 2 > 0,              % is odd
    M is floor(sqrt(N+1)),    % round-off paranoia 
    check(N, M, 3).

check(N, M, F) :- F>M.
check(N, M, F) :- F=<M,
    N mod F > 0,
    F1 is F + 2,              % test by odds only
    check(N, M, F1).

primesFromTo(F,T,X):-
  between(F,T,X), prime(X).
```

Answer (score 2):

You are mentioning `see` and `tell`: These are very old-fashioned built-in predicates. Better avoid them. Use `[file]` to load a file, and `make` to reload it.

For a better implementation of testing primes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8311574/772868).