# Prolog - omit all primary numbers in range [N-1,2]

Tags: prolog, primes

I trying to write a function - `noPrime(X,Result)` which gives a list of all the non-primary number in range `[X-1,2]`  .

For example -

```
noPrime(9,Result).
Result = [8,6,4]
```

So far I tried the follow -

```
nprimes(4,[]) :- !.
nprimes(X,[H|Rest]) :- H is X-1,nprimes(H,NewRest),
    ( isPrime(H) -> Rest = NewRest; Rest = [H|NewRest]).
```

But it gives -

```
Result = [8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4].
```

Seems like it duplicate the non-primary and gives one time the primary .

**isPrime** - is my own function which works well .

Can you detect what is the wrong here and how to correct it  ?

Comment: The term for "non primary-number" is *composite number* ;)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311046/what-is-the-bottleneck-in-this-primes-related-predicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always adding the element at the head of the second argument of `nprimes/2`.
Then, if the element is prime the second argument will still have the element; and if the element was not prime it will be added twice.

It should read:

```
nprimes(X,Rest) :- H is X-1,nprimes(H,NewRest),
    ( isPrime(H) -> Rest = NewRest; Rest = [H|NewRest]).
```